# Jfree chart and OpenSDK Issue

Tags: java, jfreechart

In our current application, I have used `JfreeChart` apis to generate chart. In one of the chart, I have used `ValueMarker` class to show one vertical line in the chart. When I am working on Windows 7 with Oracle Java SDK, everything works fine. But on Ubuntu,  this vertical line (generated by `ValueMarker` class) is not showing. The detail of our ubuntu environment is as follows:

> java version "1.6.0_20"
>   OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.9.13) (6b20-1.9.13-0ubuntu1~10.04.1)
>   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Any Pointer in this regard will be very helpful.

Comment: Looks like some rendering issue on Linux. Could you show us your code?

Comment: May be you will show us any parts of the source code or better some screenshots?

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://www.jfree.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=116384).